# Flask: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, mysql, flask, typeerror, mysql-python

So, I've been trying to add new records in a table of a database from XAMPP using Flask but I can't make this code work. Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '3307'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'pruebas'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add contact', methods=['POST'])
def add_contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Nombre = request.form['Nombre']
        Estado = request.form['Estado']
        Situacion = request.form['Situacion']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO prueba1 (Nombre, Estado, Situacion) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (Nombre, Estado, Situacion))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return 'Recibido'
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 3000, debug = True)
```

I've already try putting a the name of the columns before the %s but it doesn't work either.

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO prueba1 (Nombre, Estado, Situacion) VALUES (%(Nombre)s, %(Estado)s, %(Situacion)s)', (Nombre, Estado, Situacion))
mysql.connection.commit()
```

I link three imgs, the first one is the columns MySQL configuration, the second one is an example of how the data looks like in the table and the final one is the traceback of the error. Thanks for the help, I'm a beginner.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCLrz.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUQXP.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjWgg.png

Comment: Something you are inserting is a STRING and it needs to be an INTEGER.  And if you are confused because it IS a number, its probably one of the x = "22" is NOT x = 22 scenarios (first is a string next is an integer)  And so if this is the case you could CINT the string into an Integer assuming it is actually a number.

Comment: WHERE do you see that error?  Which line, exactly?  Did you print your form values to make sure they match your column types?

Comment: What's the full error traceback? Also, what does your data look like?

Comment: @easleyfixed MySQL will automatically convert strings to numbers when necessary.

Comment: Do you know what version they are running ?  Can we assume all version are doing this @Barmar?

Comment: @easleyfixed It has always been like this as far as I know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The value of `app.config['MYSQL_PORT']` shoulld be an integer, not a string. Get rid of the quotes around `3307`.

Comment: @Barmar yeah that was all, the quotes around 3307 value!
I don't know if you could post the answer in here or do I have to post it, but thank you man, I was one week in around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port number must be an integer, not a string.

```
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 3307
```